# How to properly use a BATCH If?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to do a pre-test for a user to see if they have python installed on
their PC.

First it will check if python is properly installed, if not it will test if python is missing and the path is just broken, if both are false if will ask if you want to download python and if yes it will go to the website. I feel like I should change to `goto` statements.

```
@echo off
color 0E

::check for python
python --version >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( color 04
    IF EXIST "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python" ( color 04
        echo Your Python is installed but not in the path.
        ) ELSE ( color 04
        echo Python is not installed on your PC, would you like to download it?
        )
    echo .
    echo Failed to Launch!
    )
pause
```

To test I deleted the PATH to python and it does not see my folder, skipping to ask if I want to download.

Comment: there's no problem with your if. What's the real problem?

Comment: To test I deleted the PATH to python and it does not see my folder, skipping to ask if I want to download.

Comment: that's important information, why didn't you include in the question? Input, expected behavior and what the program outputs must be described

Comment: You say tou removed the `path to python` - did you remove the directory from the `path` variable or did you delete the `"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python"` directory? (suggestion - simply **temporarily** rename the directory to ...\something, to avoid having to reinstall - this will make sure that where `python.exe` exists is not on the `path` [triggering fail] and it doesn't exist in the expected directory, then change the directory you check in your batch to ...\something so the directory sought exists)

Comment: Why `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python"` directory? Python could be installed somewhere else instead. Check `where /R c:\ python.exe`

Comment: @JosefZ That won't work if it's installed on a drive other than `c:`